# MYSQL my.cnf advice needed

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, apache-2.4, mariadb

I have a dedicated server Linux Cenots 6 with 16GB RAM - Apache + Nginx MYSQL 5.6 please can someone let me know if my etc/my.cnf  MYSQL configuration is ok or can it be improved

I am getting Reocurring error! the server quit without updating pid file - not sure if this is related to these settings or not

Secondly if i upgrade to MariaDb 10.3 would these same settings be ok or would changes be needed

[mysqld]

tmpdir = /tmp

innodb_file_per_table=1
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
performance-schema=0
max_allowed_packet=500M
open_files_limit=22000

tmp_table_size                 = 64M
max_heap_table_size            = 64M
query_cache_type               = 0
query_cache_size               = 32M
query_cache_limit              = 10M
max_connections                = 28
max_user_connections           = 28

table_open_cache               = 650
thread_cache_size              = 400

join_buffer_size               = 20M
read_buffer_size               = 60M
sort_buffer_size               = 60M
wait_timeout                   = 6580
connect_timeout                = 6100
bulk_insert_buffer_size        = 64M
key_buffer_size = 32M

#log_slow_queries=mysql-slow.log
long_query_time=4
log-queries-not-using-indexes=1

## performance schema

performance_schema=on
innodb_file_per_table=1
slow_query_log_file = host_name-slow.log

log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

lower_case_table_names = 2

Comment: Don't repost the same question. Instead, add the additional information into your existing question.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Not sure what you are talking about - the supposed duplicate has virtually 0 overlap with this question.

Comment: @GordanBobic If you take it as a MySQL tuning question, perhaps. But tuning isn't going to help with the problem the user is having, MySQL crashing, which he actually went into in detail in the other post. This isn't going to be useful unless that problem is solved.

Comment: See this for analysis:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning

Answer (score 0):

Set query_cache_size=0 since you have it disabled anyway.
You almost certainly shouldn't be changing sort_buffer_size as join_buffer_size, you are probably crippling the performance by setting them so absurdly high. The rest you may or may not need depending on your very specific workload.

You probably shouldn't be using MyISAM in 2020.

All of it should work with MariaDB 10.3.

Comment: Thank you should i remove or keep same "shouldn't be changing sort_buffer_size as join_buffer_size"

Comment: Those should be removed.

Comment: Thank you i will try it and monitor it and update here